# Why I cannot communicate with my s3 bucket from Moodle?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, plugins, moodle

I have recently installed a Moodle 4.0.2. It's a bitnami installation and it came with Amazon S3 repository plugin installed as well. When I try to add a file to a course and use the filepicker, it shows all the buckets, but when I click on a specific bucket, I see this error:

```
Debug info: S3::getBucket(): [InvalidRequest] The authorization mechanism you have provided is not supported. Please use AWS4-HMAC-SHA256. Error code: errorwhilecommunicatingwith
```

Any ideas how to solve this?

Answer (score 0):

Same error, moodle 4.0 native Amazon s3 repository not working with AWS4-HMAC-SHA256.

Alternative is not oficial plugin:  https://moodle.org/plugins/repository_s3bucket

Comment: Closed by moodle staf.  https://tracker.moodle.org/browse/MDL-60023. No ofical plugin is the only alternative right now.